# how to use secret variables in heroku

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

So I have an app that uses a password to access mongodb atlas database, I saved password .env file and in .gitignore I tell git not to upload it to repo. So now I can't access that password in production environment when app is deployed to heroku.
I must be doing something wrong. What is best practice to handle passwords?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheroku%5D+environment+variable

Comment: yes that solves the problem. but is that best practice , I mean if I have a dozen of env variables do i have to set them all one by one manually?

Comment: For **secret** environment variables like application passwords — yes, it's the best practice. For non-secret — you can add them to the repository.